# Core Data, check for existing Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: iphone, core-data, many-to-many

Having trouble with my first Core Data project...

I have two entities in a many to many relationship:  Quotes <<--->> Boilers.

When a user selects a Boiler in a UITableView row I want to know if that Boiler already has a relationship with the Quote that the page is managing, and toggle that relationship.

I think the code below fails because the Predicate doesn't know *which* Boiler has been selected, but I can't quite get this right...

```
   - (void)managedObjectSelected:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject
    {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Boiler"     inManagedObjectContext:managedObject.managedObjectContext]];    

    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY myQuote = %@", quote];   
    NSError *error;
    NSUInteger count = [managedObject.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if(count==0){
        [quote addMyBoilersObject:(Boiler*) managedObject];
    }
    else {
        [quote removeMyBoilersObject:(Boiler*) managedObject];
    }

    [managedObject.managedObjectContext save:&error];   

    }
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to use an NSFetchedResultsController to populate your UITableView. If you do this, then you should be able to toggle selection in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
    // Get the Boiler that was selected.
    Boiler *boiler = (Experiment *) [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (boiler)
        {
        if ([[self quote] boilers] containsObject:boiler])
            {
            // connected, so disconnect
            }
        else
            {
            // disconnected, so connect
            }

        }
    }
```

Anyway, have you tried something like this?

Comment: This seems like the right approach, but can you point me to a reference for the "contains" command in your example, the compiler doesn't like it and I'm struggling to find a tutorial.   Thanks.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part - see edit for correction. [[self quote] boilers] returns an NSSet. -containsObject: is an instance method for NSSet. Hope this helps.